# how to get value out of Arc<dyn RequestInterceptor + Send + Sync >::new() and assign to a mut variable outside in rust?

Tags: rust, mutex, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to use rust-headless-chrome to extract a request url of a XHR request using Network Request Interception method `tab.enable_request_interception(request_interceptor)`

error:

```
error[E0525]: expected a closure that implements the `Fn` trait, but this closure only implements `FnMut`
   --> .../extract_xhr_url.rs:64:13
    |
63  |            let request_interceptor: Arc<dyn RequestInterceptor + Send + Sync> = Arc::new(
    |  _______________________________________________________________________________-
64  | |/             move |_transport: Arc<Transport>,
65  | ||                   _session_id: SessionId,
66  | ||                   intercepted_event: RequestPausedEvent| {
    | ||________________________________________________________^ this closure implements `FnMut`, not `Fn`
...   |
85  | |                  xhr_url = request_url.to_owned();
    | |                  --- closure is `FnMut` because it mutates the variable `xhr_url` here
...   |
100 | |              },
101 | |          );
    | |__________- the requirement to implement `Fn` derives from here
    |
    = note: required for `[closure@.../extract_xhr_url.rs:64:13: 66:57]` to implement `RequestInterceptor`
    = note: required for the cast from `[closure@.../extract_xhr_url.rs:64:13: 66:57]` to the object type `dyn RequestInterceptor + Send + Sync`
```

code:

```
pub fn extract_xhr_url() -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {

    let main_url = "https://website.com".to_owned();
    let mut xhr_url: String;

    let browser = Browser::default()?;
    let tab = browser.new_tab()?;
    let request_pattern = RequestPattern {
        url_pattern: None,
        resource_Type: Some(ResourceType::Xhr),
        request_stage: Some(RequestStage::Request),
    };
    tab.enable_fetch(Some(&[request_pattern]), None)?;
    tab.navigate_to(&main_url)?.wait_until_navigated()?;

    let request_interceptor: Arc<dyn RequestInterceptor + Send + Sync> = Arc::new(
        move |_transport: Arc<Transport>,
              _session_id: SessionId,
              intercepted_event: RequestPausedEvent| {
            let request_url = intercepted_event.params.request.url.as_str();

            xhr_url = request_url.to_owned();

            let continue_request = ContinueRequest {
                request_id: intercepted_event.params.request_id,
                url: Some(intercepted_event.params.request.url.clone()),
                method: Some("GET".to_string()),
                post_data: None,
                headers: None,
                intercept_response: None,
            };
            RequestPausedDecision::Continue(Some(continue_request))
        },
    );

    tab.enable_request_interception(request_interceptor)?;

    Ok(xhr_url)

}
```

How do I move the value out of the Arc<dyn RequestInterceptor + Send + Sync> and re-assign it to a mutable variable outside of its scope?
Note: it cannot be wrapped inside Mutex, because tab.enable_request_interception() cannot accept a Mutex as its argument.

Is there a solution to this?
Thanks!

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Ok, so following suggestions I tried to use Arc<Mutex>, the compiler diagnostics went quiet, but it gives empty results. The value doesn't seem to be passed on outside the closure. Additionally, the console prints the value outside the closure before printing the value inside the closure. Why is this?

code rewritten:

```
pub fn extract_xhr_url() -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {

    let main_url = "https://website.com".to_owned();

    // wrap it in Arc<Mutex<String>>
    let xhr_url: Arc<Mutex<String>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(String::new()));
    // Clone the Arc for use in the closure
    let xhr_url_clone = xhr_url.clone();

    let browser = Browser::default()?;
    let tab = browser.new_tab()?;
    let request_pattern = RequestPattern {
        url_pattern: None,
        resource_Type: Some(ResourceType::Xhr),
        request_stage: Some(RequestStage::Request),
    };
    tab.enable_fetch(Some(&[request_pattern]), None)?;
    tab.navigate_to(&main_url)?.wait_until_navigated()?;

    let request_interceptor: Arc<dyn RequestInterceptor + Send + Sync> = Arc::new(
        move |_transport: Arc<Transport>,
              _session_id: SessionId,
              intercepted_event: RequestPausedEvent| {
            let request_url = intercepted_event.params.request.url.as_str();
            
            // lock it and then assign it a value
            let mut xhr_url = xhr_url_clone.lock().unwrap();
            *xhr_url = new_url.to_owned();
            // prints the value inside of the closure to console
            println!("XHR URL VALUE FROM INSIDE CLOSURE: {}", *xhr_url);

            let continue_request = ContinueRequest {
                request_id: intercepted_event.params.request_id,
                url: Some(intercepted_event.params.request.url.clone()),
                method: Some("GET".to_string()),
                post_data: None,
                headers: None,
                intercept_response: None,
            };
            RequestPausedDecision::Continue(Some(continue_request))
        },
    );

    tab.enable_request_interception(request_interceptor)?;

    // prints the value outside of the closure to console
    println!(
        "XHR URL VALUE FROM OUTSIDE CLOSURE: {}",
        *xhr_url.lock().unwrap()
    );

    Ok(xhr_url)

}
```

console:

```
XHR URL VALUE FROM OUTSIDE CLOSURE: 
XHR URL VALUE FROM INSIDE CLOSURE: https://another-website.com/foo/bar/barz
```

Comment: Wait, what happens if you move the `xhr_url` declaration into the closure?

Comment: By the way, always include the full error message. This doesn't seem to have anything to do with `Arc`s, but it's hard to tell without the whole compiler message.

Comment: @isaactfa I have edited the post to include full compiler diagnostic. Thanks

Comment: Have you also tried declaring `xhr_url` inside of the closure? I wouldn't have thought that that would be the problem, but the compiler message indicates as much.

Comment: @isaactfa the closure can only take 3 arguments

Comment: Have you omitted some other code that uses `xhr_url`? You only use it inside the closure, why don't you just declare it inside the closure?

Comment: @isaactfa oh yes, thanks for pointing that out. I just modified the code.  `xhr_url` will in fact need to be returned as a result of the entire function and then saved to the database.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Your interceptor closure will get sent of to work on some other thread while the method returns. If you want to wait until you receive the url, you could try using a [`channel`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html) to send it from the closure to the `extract_xhr_url` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the value out of an `Arc` as a mutable reference.

That's ok, though, it's not what you need anyway. What you really want to do is wrap `xhr_url` in a `Mutex` (and possibly an `Arc` if it gives you lifetime issues), so that you can mutate it *without* the lambda being a `FnMut`.

Comment: Note that it _is_ possible to get the value out of an `Arc` as a mutable reference, as long as you're the only `Arc` referencing that value: [`Arc::get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.get_mut), and its ownership taking cousing [`Arc::into_inner`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.into_inner). There's also the clone-on-write-ish [`Arc::make_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.make_mut).

Comment: I have modified the question to include the re-factored code wrapping `xhr_url` inside Arc<Mutex<T>>, although the compiler become quiet, the value printed to the console is still empty.

Comment: OK, I finally managed to get it to work with Arc<Mutex<T>>, and the reason why it's empty when printed to console is simply because the value was read before it was set